# double row length of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to double the length of a 2D array as I add values to it.  I know for a 1D an array the code for this is:

```
int oneD[] = new int[10];
//fill array here

oneD = Arrays.copyOf(oneD, 2 * oneD.length);
```

so if I have a 2D array and only want to double the amount of rows while keeping say 2 columns I figured I would just do this:

```
int twoD[][] = new int[10][2];
//fill array here

twoD = Arrays.copyOf(twoD, 2* twoD.length);
```

This however does not seem to work for the 2D array. How does one go about doubling the length of a 2D array.  In this case to make it [20][2] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case something like this would do the job:

```
public static <T> T[][] copyOf(T[][] array, int newLength) {
    // ensure that newLength >= 0
    T[][] copy = new T[newLength][];
    for (int i = 0; i < copy.length && i < array.length; i++) {
        copy[i] = Arrays.copyOf(array[i], array[i].length);
        // this should also work, just not create new array instances:
        // copy[i] = array[i];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

And you could call this method, just like you called `Arrays.copyOf()`

Comment: it seems like that should work but I keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at the Arrays.copyOf section

Comment: sorry, did not pay enough attention. I updated the for loop condition to fix that (obvious) bug...

Answer (score 5):

A 2D array in Java is an array of arrays. For doubling it, you'll have to manually iterate over each row in the array and copy all of its columns in turn.